# How do I bind XML to WPF, and have CRUD capability?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq, xaml

I've got an XML document with about 450 items in it.

```
<Customers>
    <Customer>
        <Name>XYZ</Name
        <Phone>1234567890</Phone>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <Name>ABC</Name>
        <Phone>9012345678</Phone>
    </Customer>
</Customers>
```

I need to bind this document to a form in WPF.  That part I have figured out.  I have the name bound to a ComboBox, and the phone (and other fields) bound to textblocks so that they display the info of whichever customer is selected in the combobox.  This is done in XAML.

What I need to add, though, is the ability to add/update/delete customers from the existing list, and have them be added/updated/deleted in the XML file.  What I'm thinking is that I can't do this just in XAML, and will need to somehow read the XML into a List with a class of Customer with all the properties that match the fields in the XML document.  Is that correct?  And if so, what is the simplest way to be able to do this?  Right now I'm reading on LINQ to XML, trying to figure out how to do that, but before I go there, I'm wondering if that's the simplest way to do it.

The project I'm working on at the moment is for work, where development is just something I do occasionally, but to know how to do this would be handy for a Windows Phone application idea to update one of my apps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Convert your XML to a proper, strongly typed data model implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch the Visual Studio Command line and use the xsd.exe tool to create a strongly typed DataSet that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Here is an example command:

```
xsd.exe /d /l:cs ..\MYXml.xsd /edb /o:..\Data\ /n:MyApp.Data
```

- **/d**: Creates the dataset.
- **/l:cs**: C# language.
- **..\MyXml.xsd**: Path to my xsd.
- **/edb**: Create databound xsd, this will make the dataset implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
- **/o**: Output directory.
- **/n**: Namespace of class.

You can easily load and save the generated DataSet from your xml file.

```
public MyDataSet Load(string path)
{
    MYXml ds = new MYXml();
    ds.ReadXml(path);
    return ds;
}

public void SaveChanges(MYXml ds, string path )
{
    // ds.AcceptChanges();
    ds.WriteXml(path);
}
```

### [MSDN: XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx).

Comment: Daniel - thanks very much for your reply. It took some work but I figured out how to use the xsd tool. Is it always going to be easiest to copy the xsd.exe to the directory in use, or am I doing something wrong? Now that I've got this generated class, I'm not quite sure what to do with it. Yes, I'm inexperienced at this... I see the fields and such, but how do I populate the class from the XML file?  I'll keep looking in the meantime.  Thanks!

Comment: You just use it like you'd use a regular DataSet.  For example `myDatset.aTable.First(s => s.ID == 123)`, would return the first row from `aTable` that has the ID 123.

Comment: DOH! I can't believe what an idiot I am... In your answer you answered how to load it, and somehow in working at figuring out the XSD tool, I didn't even see the code that you put in the answer. I'm sorry. Probably later today I'll look at putting it into my code and see if that works. Thanks.

Comment: Ok - was busy with something else all day yesterday. Looking at this now. In the code above, under "you can easily load and save...", in the Load method, what type is MyDataSet? Where does it come from? I'm putting this into my class with all of my other business logic, right? If I change MyDataSet to Customers (the name of my generated class), there's no ReadXML on the ds.

Comment: I wasn't consistent with the naming of things.  Whatever the name of your scheme file (in the example `MyXml`) that will be the name of your data set.  So in the old example MyDataSet was the dataset you created.  For consistency I changed it to `MyXml` in the code example too.

Comment: Ok - so I screwed it up... Ugh. I did get the dataset to load, but hadn't yet figured out how to bind it to the combobox, but then I remembered that my coworkers' computers only have .NET fx 3.5, so I changed the framework version, and that broke the generated file.  I'll have to fix that tomorrow. If the MyXML.cs implements Dataset, (public partial class Customers : global::System.Data.DataSet) I would have expected to be able to set the ComboBox's ItemsSource to ds, but I can't.

Comment: That was a quick fix.  I've got it loading the dataset again.  Thanks for your help, BTW - I appreciate it.

Comment: My boss moved me on to something else, and this project remains unfinished, so I've gone ahead and marked your answer as accepted.  Sorry for the delay.